# if increasing/decreasing, do something

Tags: c#, if-statement

I would like to check whether an integer is increasing or decreasing and then do something.

`int x = 0;`

`int y = 0;`

if `x` is increasing in value, `y --;`

Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense - an integer has a single value: whatever it is set to.  It doesn't increase or decrease. Are you looking at a sequence of numbers perhaps?

Comment: You pretty much wrote the exact code you need in your question.

Comment: It didn't work and, well, now I changed it anyway.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//loop starts
//X gets modified
if(X>tempX)
{
    //X increments
}    
else if (X<tempX)
{
    //X decrements 
}
else
    //X remains the same

int tempX=X;
//loop ends
```